# vscode minimize and closing buttons

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here][1]

anyone knows how to reset them to the default side?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcIUE.png

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589281/836330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings->Window->Tittle Bar Style, change it to native (the custom might not be working for some reason).
[image: Tittle Bar Style setting]

In your image it looks zoomed in as well. There is also a Zoom Level option in that section that you could change to address the zooming.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching in the settings **Title Bar Style** and change the setting to native. (In the dropdown menu).